# Torque on a magnetic dipole of closed flat current loop

Tags: electromagnetism

It is a simple question, but I am stuck on point concerning area calculation.

$\vec F = I \vec dl \times \vec B$

Hence torque, $\vec {dT} = \vec r \times I \vec {dl} \times \vec B$.

Hence total torque, $\int \vec {dT} = \vec T =\int (\vec r \times I \vec {dl}) \times B=I\int \vec {dA} \times \vec B=I \vec A \times \vec B=\vec m \times \vec B$.

$\vec A$ is the area vector and $\vec m$ is the magnetic moment.

**So the critical assumption is that $\vec {dA}=\vec r \times \vec {dl}$.**

If the above condition is true, then lets apply this formula to a circle.

$\int \vec r \times  \vec {dl}=\int r.r.d\theta=2\pi r^2 \ne\pi r^2$

Hence how can I apply the above assumption to calculate the area of the loop when it fails for a circle.

So,

Answer (score 1):

Your  expression
$$
d{\boldsymbol \tau}={\bf r}\times Id{\bf r}\times {\bf B}
$$
is ambiguous as
$$
{\bf a}\times ({\bf b}\times {\bf c})\ne ({\bf a}\times {\bf b})\times {\bf c}
$$
indeed for a plane figure $d(Area) = \frac 12 {\bf r}\times d{\bf r}$.

Here is a derivation of the torque for a general current ${\bf J}$:

Let ${\bf J}$ obey $\nabla \cdot {\bf J}=0$, and be of compact support. Then we have the lemma
$$
0=\int \partial^\alpha (x_\mu x_\nu J_\alpha)\, d^3 x = \int (x_\nu J_\mu + x_\mu J_\nu)\, d^3 x.  
$$
An immediate   corollary is that
$$
\int x_\mu J_\mu\, d^3x =0.
$$
Now let ${\bf B}$ be uniform.  Then the triple product formula
$$
{\bf a}\times ({\bf b}\times {\bf c})= ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf c}){\bf b} -{(\bf a}\cdot {\bf b}){\bf c}
$$
gives us
$$
\left\{\int({\bf r}\times {\bf J})\,d^3x\right\}  \times {\bf B}= \int [({\bf B}\cdot {\bf r}){\bf J}-({\bf B}\cdot {\bf J}) {\bf r} ]\, d^3x\nonumber\\
= 2 \int ({\bf B}\cdot{\bf r}) {\bf J} \,d^3 x\qquad\qquad \qquad \,\hbox{(lemma)}\nonumber\\
= 2 \int [({\bf B}\cdot{\bf r}) {\bf J} - ({\bf r}\cdot{\bf J}) {\bf B}]\, d^3 x\quad \hbox{(corollary)}\nonumber\\
=2 \int {\bf r}\times ({\bf J}\times {\bf B})\, d^3 x.\nonumber
$$
The torque on a  current system is therefore
$$
{\boldsymbol  \tau} \equiv  \int {\bf r}\times ({\bf J}\times {\bf B})\, d^3 x\nonumber\\
=\left\{  \int \frac 12({\bf r}\times {\bf J})\,d^3x\right\} \times {\bf B}\nonumber\\
= {\boldsymbol \mu}\times {\bf B},\phantom \int\nonumber
$$
where
$$
{\boldsymbol \mu}\stackrel{\rm def}{=}  \int \frac 12({\bf r}\times {\bf J})\,d^3x
$$ is the magnetic moment.

For current in a wire loop things simplify a bit, but I think you still need
$$
\oint_{\rm loop}(x_idx_j+x_jdx_i) = \oint_{\rm loop} d(x_ix_j)=0.
$$